# not able to create maven project in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I had downloaded maven api from eclipse market place.
But when I try to create any maven project, it gives me following error

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

Also when I am trying to run errored project with maven build, it gives me following error:

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
 SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Also I am unable to find my `setting.xml` file for maven. Please tell me where I should find this. I had downloaded maven from eclipse market place, so where is the home directory of maven?

Also I had found that maven is not creating any jar file of my project in repository folder.

Comment: The maven home directory is an `.m2` folder in your User home directory

Comment: Thanks harsha.....but plzz tell me how to solve this error..

Comment: @harshakumarReddy your statement is not correct at all. The settings.xml and pom.xml are quite different and serve different purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had downloaded maven from eclipse market place,

What you have downloaded is the [Maven Integration for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-luna-and-newer), also known as **[m2e (Maven for Eclipse)](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)**.

What it will allow you is to import a maven project into your Eclipse workspace.

So first, put Eclipse aside for a moment, and download maven itself from the [Maven Download page](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

> I am unable to find my `setting.xml` file for maven.Please tell me where i should find this.

You have a global one where maven has been installed: see "[Maven settings](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)".
You can override it with one manually created in `~/.m2/settings.xml` or (Windows) `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\settings.xml`.

Follow this [maven tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/) and make sure you have a small Java project where you can run manually `mvn clean install`.

*Then*, you can [import that project into Eclipse](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_eclispe_ide.htm):

[image: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/images/import_project2.jpg]